# Duration of follow-up in staggered entry survival designs

Tags: probability, clinical-trials

Suppose a clinical trial recruits $n$ patients and follows them for a maximum of $t$ years for a time-to-event outcome, like death. The objective is to find the expected number of person-years follow-up for these patients accounting for the event process. Obviously, if no events, then the person years follow is $nt$.

If the distribution of the event process $F$ is exponential with rate parameter $\theta$, I find I can agree with simulated results using $$\sum_{i=1}^nF^{-1}(i/(n+1)$$

where $F^{-1}(i/(n+1)$ is the expected event time for the $i$-th order statistic.

However, I'm a little puzzled how to adapt this for a "ramp-up" design. This is where the the patients are recruited over a fixed interval $r < t$. If we assume a triangular entry, and no events occur, then it's straightforward to calculate the expected person-years follow-up as $n(t-r)+nr/2$.

[image]

Is there a convenient closed form expression for the expected person-years follow-up when the study entry is triangular over a ramp up period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happily, as a probability problem, the calculation is relatively straightforward.

For a triangular ramp up, the maximum observation time $u_i$ is given by

$$u_i = r ((n-i)/n) + t; \quad i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$$

where $i$ denotes order of entry into the cohort.

Therefore the chances of being included in the sample as an event is given by $F(u_i)$ and the expected number of deaths in the sample at follow-up is $d = \sum_{i=1}^n F(u_i)$. The sample median $\hat{M}$ for a survival sample with censored observations is given by:

$$ \hat{M} = \log(2) \sum_i^n{\text{Event Times}_i}/d.$$

So one can easily input the median for sample median and multiply by number of deaths, dividing by $\log(2)$ to obtain the cumulative follow-up.